# Debugging scheme on vim

Tags: vim, scheme, racket

We are working on a project with scheme on UNIX terminal using vim.

We are using mzscheme (though startup prompt says *Welcome to Racket v6.1*.

Is there any way we can use vim to debug the program?
I tried using Dr.Racket with the following libraries:

```
#lang racket

#lang scheme

#lang r5rs
```

but I wasn't even able to run the program so we are thinking of just doing it in vim.

I appreciate all of your suggestion

Comment: why some people down vote so quickly? I am annoyed by such behaviour. How about if we (lisp community) try to be more inviting and encouraging for people who are new to lisp?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that [gist](https://gist.github.com/jebberjeb/21711bcac6c883b3d3de) might help.

But be aware that actually the vim vs emacs war found an end in **spacemacs** - we have just to use it and declare an end to this useless meaningless war. spacemacs is an under-the-hood-emacs but presenting itself with vim keybindings.
So this means you can use emacs (a very able lisp editor written in a lisp) to parse lisp code (be it Racket or be it emacs lisp or be it common lisp) using your beloved vim key bindings - and the interactive behaviour of vim.
(emacs is actually an operating system in your operating system. You can make it even open pdf files! I was so amazed when I saw it the first time).
You might give it a shot!

The advantage of this is that emacs is a code-aware editor for lisp code.

Maybe [that link](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/racket) will help.